# how to detect touches on the background of UINavigationController toolbar

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I'd like to detect touches (or just a tap would do) on the background to the UIToolbar supplied by a UINavigationController. Things I have tried that don't work (or that I couldn't get to work):

- adding a UITapGestureController to the UIToolbar - this fails because although it does detect the tap, it consumes touches so the buttons on the toolbar stop working (as they receive no touches)
- setting a target and action on a UIBarButtonItem that is a UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace - flexible spaces don't appear to pick up touches (which seems fair enough)

What I want is to detect any touch that is not on a button. Given that I can't set the toolbar for the UINavigationController (it is read only), so I can't substitute my own UIToolbar subclass,  is there a trick / workaround that I am missing?

Comment: Couldn't you add a big button and set its z-value to lowest? `UIToolbar` is a `UIView`, so you should be able to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code does the trick:

```
CGSize toolbarSize = [[[self navigationController] toolbar] frame].size;
UIControl* backgroundControl = [[UIControl alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, toolbarSize.width, toolbarSize.height)];
[backgroundControl addTarget:self action:@selector(toolbarBackgroundTap) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[backgroundControl setAutoresizingMask: [[[self navigationController] toolbar] autoresizingMask]];
[[[self navigationController] toolbar] insertSubview:backgroundControl atIndex:0];
[backgroundControl release];
```

@bdares - thanks for the suggestion in your comment. That was very helpful.